# Select multiple values within a single Declare statement

Tags: sql, variables, declare

```
DECLARE @account VARCHAR(12)  
SET @account = '49943725'  

DECLARE @items VARCHAR(5)  
SET @items = (SELECT item_no FROM transactions   
               WHERE account = @account   
               AND item_no IN ('81','101','108','112','113','118','187','189','190','192','193','194','195'))

SELECT 
    property, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), account) AS account,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), item_no) AS item_no,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), amount) AS amount,  
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), amt_paid) AS amt_paid, 
    status,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), tran_id) AS tran_id, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), post_date) AS post_date, 
    tran_code, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), notes) AS notes, 
    clk, invoice, charge_property, * 
FROM 
    transactions 
WHERE 
    account = @account AND item_no = @items
```

Error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Any tips on how to make @items = multiple values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any tips on how to make @items = multiple values?

No - a `VARCHAR(5)` variable can only hold one value. You can, howvere, just embed your list as a subquery:

```
SELECT 
     property, 
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), account) AS account,
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), item_no) AS item_no,
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), amount) AS amount,  
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), amt_paid) AS amt_paid, status,
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), tran_id) AS tran_id, 
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), post_date) AS post_date, tran_code, 
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), notes) AS notes, clk, invoice, charge_property, *
FROM transactions 
WHERE account = @account 
AND item_no IN (SELECT item_no FROM transactions   
               WHERE account = @account   
               AND item_no IN        
                ('81','101','108','112','113','118','187','189','190','192','193','194','195'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [table variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175010.aspx).

```
DECLARE @Account VARCHAR(12) = '49943725';
DECLARE @Items TABLE (ItemNo VARCHAR(5));

INSERT @Items (Item_no)
SELECT  item_no 
FROM    transactions   
WHERE   account = @account   
AND     item_no IN ('81','101','108','112','113','118','187','189','190','192','193','194','195');
```

Then use `IN` in your actual query:

```
AND     item_no IN (SELECT ItemNo FROM @Items);
```

Although unless your query to get items is more complicated than what you have shown, you would be just as well following D Stanley's advice and placing your query within the main query.